# How to add text-align buttons to toolbar in TinyMCE 4.x?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, toolbar

This link: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:%22For_Dummies%22 shows under the headline "Custom Advanced TinyMCE wysiwyg Editor" in the second window behind "theme_advanced_buttons" the names of the buttons you can add to your toolbar. It's a bit different in version 4.x but it works the following way:

```
$('#my_textarea').tinymce({
    plugins: 'link,code,preview,autolink',             
    height: 350,
    width: 750,
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | justifyleft justifycenter justifyright | bullist numlist | link image | preview code"
});
```

Except the `justifyleft justifycenter justifyright` buttons everything works perfect. So how to find out the right button names for these buttons?

Comment: This bit me too. The problem is that WordPress 3.9 introduced an update to TinyMCE that changed the name of the text alignment buttons (maybe without warning?). That means as soon as you upgrade WordPress, the text alignment buttons will vanish if you're using the earlier symbol names. To grumble: would it have killed them to keep the old names as aliases for the new ones temporarily?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

```
alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify
```

works